# How create only index script of all tables from database in MS SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to generate a script of all the indexes in a database(Create Index).

From database -> Task -> Generate script option get only create table with primary key index. So I want other indexes. how can we generate it in SQL Server. There needs to be separate script for Clustered and Non Clustered Indexes.

Comment: You can include other indexes in SSMS generated scripts by selecting this option from the tools menu:  Tools-->Options-->SQL Server Explorer-->Scripting-->Script indexes.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman, I have get this option under Task -> Generate script -> select tables --> click on Advance option. Advance scripting option has "Script Indexes" option which is default  False set, now I have set "Script Indexes" as True and its work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSMS scripting options are configurable. To include non-constraint indexes in the SSMS generated scripts, change the Script indexes option to true from the tools menu under Tools-->Options-->SQL Server Explorer-->Scripting-->.

In cases where SSMS scripting is insufficient for your needs, you can use SMO (e.g. [Scripter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scripter) via PowerShell or .NET code) or the cross-platform [mssql-scripter](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter) command-line utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can reveal the existing indices easily:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE type_desc='CLUSTERED'
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE type_desc='NONCLUSTERED'
```

When you say you want to "generate a script of all the indexes in a database", why?  Your DDL should create all the indexes as you create tables.

Comment: Thanks I will check it again. when I have generated script, the script contains only table and primary key index.

Comment: Sorry, it won't happen automatically- what I mean to say is that you should put your index creation in with your DDL so that everything is set up correctly from the start.